How to remove an object from a scene with Python?
I have an object that I would like to remove:
my_obj = bpy.data.objects['my_obj']

I have 2 scenes:
my_scene_1 = bpy.data.scenes['my_scene_1 ']
my_scene_2 = bpy.data.scenes['my_scene_2 ']

The my_obj is present in both scenes.
I would like to remove my_obj from my_scene_2, which is not necessarily the context scene and I would like to avoid my_scene_2 becoming the context scene.
Obviously the my_obj must remain in the my_scene_1
I would like to avoid using Blender operators

Hello ! I think it should be clarified in the question whether you want to remove an object from a scene's objects or from a scene's collection's objects. Scenes can only contain objects directly through their main collection : scene.objects. However if the scene contains a collection that contains objects, these will appear in scene.all_objects but not in scene.objects.

bpy.data.scenes["my_scene_2"].collection.objects.unlink(obj)
Scenes contain all their objects in main "Scene Collection". If you unlink from that it should be removed.

If your object is present in both scenes, it means they are linked. Removing from one scene will remove from another as well.
to remove the object
import bpy

my_obj = bpy.data.objects['my_obj']

bpy.data.objects.remove(my_obj)



Hello, I don't think the first sentence is true, can you elaborate on why one can't unlink an object from a scene without unlinking it from another one ?
